# how to import AD User attribute value in powershell

Tags: active-directory, synchronization, powershell-2.0

I would like to AD User sync with powershell.
I have 2 different AD server which domain is also different.
I'd like to copy users with all attribute value to the other AD server.

1. Import User with powershell

```
get-aduser –filter * -property * | select-object name,userPrincipalName,sAMAccountName,CN,givenName,initials,sn,displayName,description,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,telephoneNumber,otherTelephone,mail,destinationOU,l,c,memberOf,homePhone,otherHomePhone,pager,otherpager,mobile,othermobile,ipPhone,otheripPhone,info,title,department,company,manager,mailenabled,mailNickname,proxyAddresses,targetAddress,displayNamePrintable,msExchHideFromAddressLists,mAPIRecipient,AutoUpdateOnRecipientPolicy,extensionAttribute1,extensionAttribute2,extensionAttribute3,extensionAttribute4,extensionAttribute5,extensionAttribute6,extensionAttribute7,extensionAttribute8,extensionAttribute9 | export-CSV users.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

I saved this csv again to unicode txt type.
And there was all filed and attribute value that i wanted to export.

2. Export User to the other AD Server like as below:

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" D:\uni.txt | New-ADUser
```

There were no Error message with import but when i see all from AD server.
There was not attribute that i exported.
only a few things could get import the value(name,title,department,)
but i could not get attribute(extensionattribute, mail,etc)

do you have any idea about it? or have done for sync with powershell?
And do you happen to know about adding memoberOf also?

Comment: Which commands/steps did you use to export and import the data?

Comment: there is command 1 and 2